# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-ax^2 + bx +c}} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Is there a way to solve this integral?

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-ax^2 + bx +c}}, \;\;\;\;\; \forall\; a,b,c \in (0,+\infty) \;in\;R$$

I have tried it by changing of variable and by parts, but no result. I don't know what else to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are $a,b,c$?

Comment: What do you mean when you say “I have proved it by changing of variable and by parts”?

Comment: They are constants. But I'll check it now. "Change of variable" and "Parts" are two methods to solve integrals. That's what we call it in my country. Maybe "Change of variable" is also known by "Substitution".

Comment: Do you mean *tried* instead of *proved* ? [Italian native ? Mind the false friend.]

Comment: Thank you, tried.

Comment: It is very general question because Delta can be negative or zero or positive

Comment: What do you mean by Delta?

Comment: Quadratic equation in denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-ax^2 + bx +c}}
=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{b^2+4ac}{4a}-a(x-\frac b{2a})^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt a}\sin^{-1}
\frac{2ax-b}{\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint #1: $ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a})$

Hint #2: it is possible to find $\quad p, q \quad$ such that: $\quad (x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}) = (x+p)^2 \pm q$

Hint #3: a substitution $\quad x+p = t \quad$ will work...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there are remaining sign errors in what follows.

---

Set

$$ax^2+bx+c=(px+q)^2r+|r|,$$

which is achieved by

$$\begin{cases}a=p^2r,\\b=2pqr,\\c=q^2r+|r|.\end{cases}$$

As the sign of $r$ must match that of $a$, the solution is

$$\begin{cases}r=\dfrac{|b^2-4ac|}{4a},\\p=\sqrt{\dfrac ar},\\q=\dfrac{b}{2pr}.\end{cases}$$

By applying the change of variable

$$t=px+q,$$

this gives
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}=\frac1{p}\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{|r|(1+\text{sgn(r)}t^2)}},$$

the antiderivatives of which are $\text{arsinh }t$, $\arcsin t$ or do-not-exist, depending on the signs.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by completing the square in $ax^2+bx+c$.  Then you get something like
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-a}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\beta^2 - (x-\alpha)^2
}}
=
{\frac {1}{\sqrt {-a}}\arcsin \left( {\frac {x-\alpha}{\beta}}
 \right) }
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\alpha)^2 + \beta^2}}
={\frac {\ln  \left( x-\alpha+\sqrt {{\alpha}^{2}-2\,x\alpha+{\beta}^{2
}+{x}^{2}} \right) }{\sqrt {a}}}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\alpha)^2 - \beta^2}}
=
{\frac {\ln  \left( x-\alpha+\sqrt {{\alpha}^{2}-2\,x\alpha-{\beta}^{2
}+{x}^{2}} \right) }{\sqrt {a}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.*

If $a=0,$ the integral is what you can do, presumably. So first let $a\ne 0.$

Secondly, the quadratic expression $ax^2+bx+c$ may be put either as a perfect square, a sum of two squares, or a difference of two squares depending on the sign of the quantity $\Delta=b^2-4ac,$ which is called its discriminant.

If you can write $ax^2+bx+c$ as $(px+q)^2$ for some $p,q$ depending on $a\ne 0,b,c,$ then again the integral is presumably one you can do. This happens when $\Delta=0.$

Or you may be able to write the quadratic expression as $(px+q)^2-k^2,$ in that case you may use a suitable trigonometric substitution (usually involving a sine). Or as $k^2-(px+q)^2,$ for which you may use a secant substitution.

Or if the expression is of the form $(px+q)^2+k^2,$ then we may use a tangent substitution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Use the substitution
\begin{equation}
u = \frac{2 a x + b}{\sqrt{|\Delta|}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

A prime candidate for [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution).

$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-ax^2+bx+c}} &= -2 \int \frac{dt}{\frac{b-2\sqrt c\,t}{a+t^2}t+\sqrt c} \frac{a\sqrt c+bt-\sqrt c\,t^2}{(a+t^2)^2} \\
&= -2 \int \frac{dt}{a+t^2} \\
&= -\frac2{\sqrt a} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac t{\sqrt a}\right) + C \\
&= \boxed{-\frac2{\sqrt a} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-ax^2+bx+c}-\sqrt c}{\sqrt a\,x}\right) + C}
\end{align*}$$

where we made the replacement

$$t=\frac{\sqrt{-ax^2+b+c}-\sqrt c}{x} \iff x=\frac{b-2\sqrt c\,t}{a+t^2} \implies dx = -\frac{2a\sqrt c+2bt-2\sqrt c\,t^2}{(a+t^2)^2}\,dt$$