# How to integrate $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$

Tags: integration

Let
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$$
I know this can be either
$$\displaystyle I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\ln\left({2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+2ax+b}\right)+C$$
$$\displaystyle I=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-a}}\arcsin{\left(\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\right)}+C$$
Or
$$I=\frac1{\sqrt{a}}\mathrm{arcsinh}\left(\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\right)+C$$

Can you tell me the difference between these three solutions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-ax^2 + bx +c}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540383/integrate-int-fracdx-sqrt-ax2-bx-c)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436768/substitution-for-int-frac-dx-ax2-bx-c

Comment: Oh no! It's Kira

Comment: @Zen the first equation is incorrect, missing integral!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a>0$.  Complete the square.  You get one of these cases:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\beta)^2}},\qquad \beta\in \mathbb R,\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\beta)^2+\gamma^2}},\qquad \beta\in \mathbb R, \gamma > 0,\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\beta)^2-\gamma^2}},\qquad \beta\in \mathbb R, \gamma > 0 .
$$
The first one has a "$\log$" solution, the second one has an "$\arcsin$" solution, the third one has an "$\text{asinh}$" solution.

There are three similar cases when $a<0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\displaystyle I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\ln\left({2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+2ax+b}\right)+C
\label{eq1} \tag{eq1}\\
$$

$$
\displaystyle I=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-a}}\arcsin{\left(\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\right)}+C
\label{eq2} \tag{eq2}\\
$$

$$
I=\frac1{\sqrt{a}}\mathrm{arcsinh}\left(\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\right)+C
\label{eq3} \tag{eq3}\\
$$

**First, \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq3} are the same.**
$$\text{arcsinh} (x/a) = \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 + a^2})-\ln a.$$

**Second, \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3} are different.**

\eqref{eq2} holds, when $a<0$ and $b^2-4ac> 0$.

\eqref{eq2} holds, when $a>0$ and $b^2-4ac< 0$.