# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there a way to solve $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$ ?

i tried a lot of methods such as variable changing and by partition but no one worked.

i know the results will be different depends on $\Delta$ but i couldn't figure it how

Thanks in advance

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540383/integrate-int-fracdx-sqrt-ax2-bx-c?rq=1

Comment: In my opinion, if this problem is from a book or class, then you have a serious complaint with your teacher.  You should have been handed the following formula, rather than having to **re-invent** the wheel.  In general, $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{r^2 + (sx + t)^2}}$$ will succumb to $$sx + t = r\tan(y).$$  Therefore, it is just a matter of converting the original problem into the proper format where you can apply the formula.

Comment: Just in case, you also have that  In general, $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-r^2 + (sx + t)^2}}$$ will succumb to $$sx + t = r\sec(y).$$

Comment: Again, just in case, you also have that in general $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{r^2 - (sx + t)^2}}$$ will succumb to $$sx + t = r\sin(y).$$